# Enter event in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

i m using text field to get some integer value. After entering value and hitting ENTER, i want to hide keyboard. How can i do that?

Comment: i m using text field, after entering value and hitting enter i want to hide keyboard. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The UIResponder class defines an interface for objects that respond to and handle events.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html